# I am making a toaster component in react but it is not rendering anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The toaster component is made programatically and i am passing the message through another component.

my Toaster component Looks like this:-

```
export default class MyToaster extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.toaster = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            message: [],
            show: false
        };
        this.state.message = this.props.message;

    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({show: false})
    }

    createtoaster() {
        let toastmessage = [];
      if ( this.state.show === true) {
        for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.message.length; i++) {
            let tmessage = <div className="col-md-3 offset-md-8">
                <div className="card-header">
                    <h3 className="card-title">Toast</h3>
                </div>

                <div className="card-body">
                    {this.state.message[i]}
                </div>

                <div className="card-footer">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClose()}>x</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            toastmessage.push(tmessage);
        }
        return (toastmessage);
    }
  }



    render() {

        return (
            <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-9">
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.setState({show:true})}>show Toaster</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Also this is my PostCard.js page in which the toaster component is called and message is passed.

```
export default class MyCard extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentPage: this.props.pgNo,
            details: [],
            id: null,
            index: 0
        }
        this.message = 'osihfosihfoi';
    }


    AddButton() {
        return (
            <Link to={`${this.props.url}/addnew${this.props.url}`}>

                <button
                    style={{
                    float: "right"
                }}
                    className="btn btn-primary"><Faplus/>
                </button>

            </Link>
        );
    }
    closeAfter7 = () => toast("7 Kingdoms", {autoClose: 7000});

    fetchMoreData = () => {
        if(this.state.index<100){
        this.setState({
            index: this.state.index + 5
        })
    }}
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
        this.fetchMoreData();
    }

    onScroll = () => {
        $(window).scroll(() => {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                this.fetchMoreData();
            }
        });
    }

    createCard = () => {
        let cardBody = [];
        for (let i = this.state.currentPage; i < this.state.index; i++) {

            let card = <div className="content">
                <div className="container-fluid">

                    <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-header">
                                <h3 className="card-title"></h3>
                            </div>

                            <div className="card-body">
                                <h5>
                                    ID :
                                </h5>{this.props.data[i].id}<br/>
                                <h5>
                                    User ID :
                                </h5>{this.props.data[i].userId}<br/>
                                <h5>
                                    Title :
                                </h5>{this.props.data[i].title}<br/>
                                <h5>
                                    Body :
                                </h5>{this.props.data[i].body}<br/>

                            </div>

                            <div className="card-footer clearfix"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            cardBody.push(card);
        }
        return (cardBody)

    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-10">{this.AddButton()}

                </div>
                <Toaster message={this.message}/>

                {/* <div id="snackbar" style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>Hogaya.</div> */}

                <div>

                    {this.createCard()}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

My UI renders the Show toaster button but not do anything when it is clicked. Also it dosent give any errors. Can't figure out the problem so if anyone can point out what i am doing wrong it ll be great. Also Please let me know if I am not using the correct method or logic.
TIA.

Comment: What is the content of this.state.message? If this list is empty, `createtoaster` won't render anything.

Comment: Add a working example using jsfiddle or the StackOverflow embedded editor, please.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not rendering anything because I wasn't rendering my createtoaster component. the correct way is that in my toaster component i should render it like this

```
render() {
        return (
                <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-9">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleOpen}></button>
                    {this.createtoaster()}

                </div>
        )
        }
    }
```